# TypeError on static method of mongoose model

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using node.js along with the MongoDb driver [Mongoose 3.6.1](http://mongoosejs.com/index.html). This is my schema definition:

### models/user.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
            ...
});

module.exports = {
    model : mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
};

userSchema.statics.doSomething = function () {
    console.log("I'm doing something");
}
```

Then in a separate controller, I do

### controllers/another.js

```
var User = require("../models/user").model;

function foo() {
    User.doSomething();
}
```

and I get the following error

```
[TypeError: Object function model(doc, fields, skipId) {
       if (!(this instanceof model))
         return new model(doc, fields, skipId);
       Model.call(this, doc, fields, skipId);
     } has no method 'doSomething']
```

However, if I dump the `User` object I can see the method there, as expected. This is the relevant part of the dump confirming that

```
...
schema:
 { statics:
    { doSomething: [Function] }
...
```

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: is `new Schema({` = `new mongoose.Schema({` ?

Comment: Yes it is. I forgot to include it in the snippet

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to set the static method *before* you create your model:

```
userSchema.statics.doSomething = function () {
  var User = mongoose.model('User');
  // I think 'this' also points to the User model here:
  // var User = this;
  // var user = new User(...);
  console.log("I'm doing something");
}

module.exports = {
  model : mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
};
```

Models are, to use the Mongoose terminology, "compiled" from schemas. Once you created a model, any changes to the schema aren't propagated to the model that's derived from it.

Comment: thank you! I'm a novice with mongoose and I totally missed that. But what if I need to refer to the model inside one of the statics? As an example, suppose one static method is used to create a `User` instance. Or also what if I need to refer from one static to another?

Comment: You can retrieve the model class in your static method using `mongoose.model('User')`.

Comment: Ok, so if my understanding is correct I cannot declare a convenience variable for the model on top of my static declarations and use it, because that would "freeze" the model to the incomplete schema. I will always have to user `model('User')` inside my statics. Correct?

Comment: See my edit. I ran a quick test, `this` in your statics points to the model class as well, so you can use `var user = new this({...})` to create a new instance in your static methods.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot! I'm accepting your answer, even though I still have a problem that might be related. Any reason why `var User = require("./user.js").model;` placed in another model should return `undefined`? I'm about to open another question, but maybe you have a quick answer to that

Comment: No sorry, don't see an obvious reason why it would fail :(

Comment: I found out it was a circular dependency between models. Thank you again ;)

Comment: Hey! First, thanks for the solution (working here too). And Second, do you think it's a bad practice? (to create a new instance of the model in a static method).

Comment: @VinceOPS I don't think so, it's basically what [`Model.create()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create) does, too.